# JSON Schema Validator in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class for Json Validation

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("Key", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Value", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Type", Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And my requirement is to validate a JSON against my `AttributeValue` (format is below)

```
[{"Key":"Color","Value":"Pink","Type":"Simple"},{"Key":"Material","Value":"Silver","Type":"Simple"}]
```

My code is

```cs
if (objProductInfo.Products.AttributeValue != null)
{
    var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(List<RootObject>));
    JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(objProductInfo.Products.AttributeValue);
    bool isValidSchema = jsonArray.IsValid(schema);
    if (!isValidSchema)
    {
        objProductInfo.Products.AttributeValue = null;
    }
}
```

Here it's validating most cases but the issue is that if the format like below

```
 [{"Title":"Color","Key":"Color","Value":"Pink","Type":"Simple"}]
```

Two Issues am facing

1. here we have one additional property is "Title".This is not a valid one but
   it's showing as valid.
2. Even if forget to put Double quotes on any keys it will showing as valid
   eg:
   [{"Title":"Color","Key":"Color",Value:"Pink","Type":"Simple"}]

   Here `Value` has no quotes.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the schema accept additional properties:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchema_AllowAdditionalProperties.htm

You can override this setting in the schema instance :

```cs
public static void NotAllowAdditional(JSchema schema)
{
    schema.AllowAdditionalProperties = false;
    schema.AllowAdditionalItems = false;
    foreach (var child in schema.Items)
    {
        NotAllowAdditionalProperties(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have given the AllowAdditionalProperties  and AllowAdditionalItems false,But still  it's not fixed.

Comment: You need set AllowAdditional* in all schema tree, like in the example method `NotAllowAdditional` when `foreach (var child in schema.Items)`.